# Issues with ListView & File Output

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have so many issues with my project, i really don't know where to begin.  First off, i get an error "an object reference is required for non-static field, method or property".  It underlines retPath (the line: DriveRecursion_results.DriveRecursion(retPath);).  I have no idea how to fix this.

THe other thing i'm still stumped on is how to populate a listview on my Windows Form.  What i want is a list of files that need to be renamed (versus a list of all files in my list.)

Can anybody help?  I have been struggling miserably with this for several hours now.

Here is my code:

Form1.cs:

```
namespace FileMigration
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderSelect("Please select:");
    }
    public string FolderSelect(string txtPrompt)
    {
        //Value to be returned
        string result = string.Empty;

        //Now, we want to use the path information to population our folder selection initial location
        string initialCheckoutPathDir = (@"C:\");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(initialCheckoutPathDir);
        FolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderSelect.SelectedPath = info.FullName;
        FolderSelect.Description = txtPrompt;
        FolderSelect.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if (FolderSelect.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string retPath = FolderSelect.SelectedPath;
            if (retPath == null)
            {
                retPath = "";
              }
            DriveRecursion_Results ds = new DriveRecursion_Results();
           ds(retPath);
            result = retPath;
            //Close this form.

        } 
        return result;
    }



   }
}
```

Here is DriveRecursion_Results.cs:

```
namespace FileMigration
{
public partial class DriveRecursion_Results : Form
{
    public DriveRecursion_Results()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fileOutput_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void DriveRecursion(string retPath)
    {

       // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
        string replacement = "";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> filePath = new List<string>();

        foreach (string fileNames in fileDrive)
        {
            if (regEx.IsMatch(fileNames))
            {
                filePath.Add(fileNames);
                //I tried adding my listview (fileOptions) here but I cannot for some reason
            }
        }

        }





        }




    }
```

ANY help would really be appreciated :(  Does anybody have any ideas on how to change my code so it actually works?

Comment: EDITED:  now both methods are NON-static and that took care of the error I got with retPath.  However, anybody have ideas for issue #2 with having the listview display an output of only files that need to be renamed?

Comment: What code have you already tried for adding items to your listview? Now that the method is not static you should just be able to call ListView.Items.Add("Item");

Comment: i did that -- however when i ran my app, i only got the dialogue for picking the drive & folder and NOT the list.  is it b/c i haven't put anything in private void fileOutput_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) ?  If that's the case, what do i need to put in there to make sure my app knows to displays the listview with the output of files that need to be changed?

Comment: i also want to mention - in Form1.cs, i have a button on a form that triggers the FolderBrowserDialog.  However, once the user picks the drive, the Windows Form window with the button still remains.  Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: To close the form where you have the comment //Close this form, you can call this.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to add items to your list view because you are trying to add them from a static method.

Since it is static there is no `ListView` because there isn't actually a `Form` to add things to.  You will need to make `DriveRecursion()` not static in order to add things to the `ListView`.

Additionally, when you make `DriveRecursion()` not static, you will need a way to let `Form1` know which `DriveRecursion_Results` class to populate.

Another approach you could take is having `Form1` return `retPath` to `DriveRecursion_Results`.

**Edit**

*Removed irrelevant parts of my original answer*

I have copied your code exactly how you posted it. And then made the following changes to FolderSelect() in Form1.cs When I run this code. I can get the second window to pop up, but not the other window to close, because that will cause the application to quit.

Please make sure you have ds.Show() and do at some point call ds.DriveRecursion(retPath)

Modified FolderSelect(string) in Form1.cs:

```
    private void FolderSelect( string txtPrompt )
    {
        //Value to be returned
        string result = string.Empty;

        //Now, we want to use the path information to population our folder selection initial location
        string initialCheckoutPathDir = ( "C:\\" );
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo( initialCheckoutPathDir );
        FolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderSelect.SelectedPath = info.FullName;
        FolderSelect.Description = txtPrompt;
        FolderSelect.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if( FolderSelect.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            string retPath = FolderSelect.SelectedPath;
            if( retPath == null )
            {
                retPath = "";
            }
            DriveRecursion_Results ds = new DriveRecursion_Results();
            ds.DriveRecursion( retPath );
            ds.Show();
            result = retPath;
            //Close this form.

        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: i'm still having trouble getting my initial Form1 to close.  I want it so that once the user presses 'ok' on the filebrowserdialog, the form closes and moves onto the next form (the List of files needing to be renamed).

Comment: I am guessing that you are encountering the same problem I am when trying to close the form with this.Close() -- that the entire application quits. This is because the form which started the application Form1 is now closed, so the application quits before you get a chance to see DriveRecursion_Results. I will post an edit in a few seconds.

Comment: actually my app doesn't close -- nothing closes.  the Form1 doesn't close (the form containing the single button the user presses to prompt the FileBrowserDialog).  It seems nothing happens even after the user is done picking the drive & folder they want the app to drill into.

Comment: i tried the edit...and here's the problem.  (Perhaps i was unclear and I apologize).  So Form1 needs to show up.  It has one button, that when a user clicks on it, prompts the FileBrowserDialog to display.  What i want is once the user presses 'OK' after choosing the drive & folder, the Form1 form closes.  After a few seconds, my app then runs through the files and chooses which files need to be renamed.  The output of this should show up in the DriveRecursion_Results window.  I'm still not able to close Form1 -- perhaps that is why DriveRecursion_Results doesn't appear shortly afterwards?

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I have copied your code exactly from what you have given. I made some assumptions on the layout in the form designer. But when I run this code I can get the DriveRecursion_Results window to show up. Like I said the first window doesn't close, but that's because closing it causes the application to quit.

Comment: ok now i see the listview...however it's empty.  I tried putting my listview inside my foreach loop (the last one where it's populating the FileNames) but it's still not displaying any output.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with your updated code. I have not had any problems viewing items in my list view.

Comment: actually i figured out what the problem was -- it had some property set on it that made it not populate.  THANK YOU FOR THE HELP.  MUCH appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1: your function is static. If it stops being such, this will work. This is because a static function does not have this hidden 'this' argument - the reference to object it acts upon. So, it can only access static data members, not regular ones.

Comment: i got rid of static -- so both methods now are non-static.  however, i still get the "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property) in the same exact place

Comment: My guess is that you left the rest of the code alone so you still have DriveRecursion_Result.DriveRecursion(retPath). You now need a specific DriveRecursion_Result to call DriveRecursion on. You will need to have an instance of a DriveRecursion_Result class and call DriveRecursion on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the items to your listview from that level because the listview is non-static and the method DriveRecursion is static. I would start by changing the DriveRecursion method to be non-static or return a list of file paths.